# Chart js axes padding

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I would like to use [mirror](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#common-tick-options-to-all-cartesian-axes) option in order to show y-axis value "inside" the graph:

[image]

now the problem is the x-axis should start after those values but I can't move them.

The chart is build with following code:

```js
this.chart = new Chart(this.canvas.nativeElement, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: data,
      options: {
        scales: {
          x: {
            stacked: true,
            grid: {
              display: false,
              drawBorder: false
            },
            ticks: {
              color: '#333',
              font: {
                weight: 'bold'
              },
              maxRotation: 0,
              maxTicksLimit: this.loadLabels()?.length / 2
            },
            bounds: 'ticks'
          },
          y: {
            type: 'linear',
            beginAtZero: true,
            stacked: true,
            title: {
              display: false,
            },
            display: true,
            grid: {
              display: true,
              drawBorder: false,
              lineWidth: 1,
              borderColor: 'rgb(244, 244, 244, 0.7)',
              color: 'rgb(244, 244, 244, 0.7)'
            },
            ticks: {
              display: true,
              maxTicksLimit: 5,
              mirror: true,
              callback: (val) => formatCurrency(+val, 'it', getCurrencySymbol(this.currency, 'narrow'), this.currency)
            }
          }
        }
      },
    });
```

I tried both `padding` and `grace` options without success.. Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: I think that it's working as designed, with 'mirror' option.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `y.ticks.padding` as follows:

```
y: {
  ticks: {
    ... 
    padding: -50
  }
}
```

Together with this, you also need to define `layout.padding.left` to make sure, the tick labels still appear on the `canvas`.

```
options: {
  layout: {
    padding: {
      left: 100
    }
  }
  ...
```

Obviously you need to adapt the numbers to your needs.

> For further information, please consult [Tick Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration) and [Padding](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/padding.html#padding) from the Chart.js documentation.